# Due Diligence: Habit forming medications

Tags: medical, health

What responsibility do patients have to make informed decisions?

Opioids are known to be [habit forming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opioid_use_disorder) throughout [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Opium_War).   Given the context of Purdue's Oxycontin.

Let us assume this [statement](https://www.addictioncenter.com/news/2021/12/purdue-bankruptcy-settlement-overturned/) is true:

> Purdue Pharma still led healthcare providers to believe that the
> Opioid was a non-habit-forming solution to help patients manage their
> pain safely.

Let us also assume that [Oxycontin bottles are labeled](https://%E2%80%9CWARNING:%20May%20be%20Habit%20Forming%E2%80%9D%20%20%E2%80%9COxyContin%20is%20a%20mu-agonist%20with%20an%20abuse%20liability%20similar%20to%20morphine,%20and%20is%20a%20Schedule%20II%20controlled%20substance.%E2%80%9D%20%20%E2%80%9COxycodone%20products%20are%20common%20targets%20for%20both%20drug%20abusers%20and%20addicts.%E2%80%9D%20%20%E2%80%9CPatients%20should%20be%20advised%20that%20OxyContin%20is%20a%20potential%20drug%20of%20abuse.%20%20They%20should%20protect%20it%20from%20theft,%20and%20it%20should%20never%20be%20given%20to%20anyone%20other%20than%20the%20individual%20for%20whom%20it%20was%20prescribed.%E2%80%9D%20%20%E2%80%9CPhysicians%20should%20be%20aware%20that%20psychological%20dependence%20may%20not%20be%20accompanied%20by%20concurrent%20tolerance%20and%20symptoms%20of%20physical%20dependence%20in%20all%20addicts.%20%20In%20addition,%20abuse%20of%20opioids%20can%20occur%20in%20the%20absence%20of%20true%20psychological%20dependence%20and%20is%20characterized%20by%20misuse%20for%20non-medical%20purposes.%E2%80%9D):

> “WARNING: May be Habit Forming”
>
> “OxyContin is a mu-agonist with an abuse liability similar to
> morphine, and is a Schedule II controlled substance.”
>
> “Oxycodone products are common targets for both drug abusers and
> addicts.”
>
> “Patients should be advised that OxyContin is a potential drug of
> abuse.  They should protect it from theft, and it should never be
> given to anyone other than the individual for whom it was prescribed.”
>
> “Physicians should be aware that psychological dependence may not be
> accompanied by concurrent tolerance and symptoms of physical
> dependence in all addicts.  In addition, abuse of opioids can occur in
> the absence of true psychological dependence and is characterized by
> misuse for non-medical purposes.”

Did patients have any responsibility to research / read labels and understand the risk associated with opiates?

Comment: And if they still pay doctors to push a habit forming drug even in cases when it is not needed? Patients should not be needing to do research on the medicine their doctors provide it should be done by the doctors and the makers of the drugs should be providing accurate information to the doctors and not paying them to push drugs.

Comment: Legal responsibilities don't exist in the abstract. This might be a contributory negligence argument in a medical malpractice lawsuit brought by the patient, or in a products liability case brought by a user of a drug, but duties don't exist free standing from affirmative legal claims.

Comment: Complicating matters is that your 2nd assumption is questionable. The original label for Oxycontin said ["Delayed absorption as provided by OxyContin tablets, is believed to **reduce** the abuse liability of a drug.”](https://www.statnews.com/2020/01/09/prescriber-fears-oxycontin-misuse-purdue-pharma-sales-reps-misleadingly-played-up-safety/) This claim was not removed until 2001.

Answer (score 3):

The question of a patient's legal responsibility would arise under a negligence lawsuit, where the patient "should have known". The standard for determining what things a person "should have known" is fluid, but obviously you can start with "could have known". If a patient's can't know a fact, they cannot be said to have negligently contributed to the damage. Doctors are given these warnings, but patients are not, uniformly. It is therefore possible that a patient was never warned of the effects of an opioid prescription (I can personally attest to that lacuna in the system). Your assumption about the bottle being so labeled is only valid for the original supply bottles from which the pharmacist dispenses.

However, there is also a rather compelling argument to the effect that no person in the US can in fact be unaware of the addiction risk of opioids. It is a defeasible argument, possibly applicable to a hypothetical person who has lived in complete isolation for decades.

A patient is not required to undertake independent research in order to validate the science that underlies statutorily-mandated FDA approval or drugs, instead, the burden is assigned to the manufacturers and distributors (primarily doctors and pharmacists) to convey the relevant information. Thus HR 1026 would, if enacted, mandate a different warning. But the bill does not assert a lack of liability on either side, therefore the question reduces to the "simple" matter of determining if a person knew or should have known.

Comment: Can a patient be held responsible for knowing if the doctors give them this as the only option?